# How can I make a symbol visible only if other two symbols are visible in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to make a symbol visible (symbol3) only if symbol1 and symbol2 are visible in ActionScript 3.0 (Adobe Animate CC), but I can't make it, because I am really new in programming... Can anyone help me? I have this code:

```
symbol1.visible = false;
symbol2.visible = false;
symbol3.visible = false;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide_1);

function fl_ClickToHide_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    symbol1.visible = true;
}

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide_2);

function fl_ClickToHide_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    symbol2.visible = true;
}

symbol3.visible = symbol2.visible && symbol1.visible
```

Thanks a lot,

Tom

Comment: `symbol3.visible = symbol1.visible && symbol2.visible;`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. You just need to call it in right place.

Comment: I forgot to say that there is one thing... Symbol1 and Symbol2 are inicially not visible...

Comment: Well, without any code provided how can we tell what is going on?

Comment: Sorry, I am going to edit my question with the code...

Comment: Can you update your initial question with the code ?

Comment: I have updated now the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work for you is because `symbol3.visible = symbol2.visible && symbol1.visible;` is being executed right after all is hidden and buttons listeners were added. After you click buttons only code in `fl_ClickToHide_1` or `fl_ClickToHide_2` is being executed and in there you just change visibility of one symbol. If you want to execute checking after click you can do something like that:

```
symbol1.visible = false;
symbol2.visible = false;
symbol3.visible = false;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide_1);

function fl_ClickToHide_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    symbol1.visible = true;
    do_magic();
}

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide_2);

function fl_ClickToHide_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    symbol2.visible = true;
    do_magic();
}

function do_magic():void
{
    symbol3.visible = symbol2.visible && symbol1.visible;
}
```

Comment: Is this proper? Visible = x && y? I've not seen that before. If that works it is a nice shortcut I shall start implementing.  I would have thought to use an if statement here.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks.